# Should my logic be on Fragments or on Activities?

Tags: java, android

I am currently building an android app. I have implemented some fragments and some activities, and now I need to access the database, do some logic and update some fragment elements.

Should I access the database and do the logic on the fragment's side OR on the activity and then send the data to the fragments, and why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you do this (I don't want to go into design patterns).

1. If the operations (which manipulates the UI of the Activity and not the Fragment) you want to perform is going to be accessed by many Fragments then better to do that in activity.
2. If the operations (which manipulates the UI only the Fragment) you want to perform is going to affect only one Fragment then its better to do that in that Fragment itself.
3. If you want to do the manipulation type of operation on the data fetched from Database then why don't you do that in DB helper class only and pass on the result.
4. If the operation you want to perform is neither UI related nor on the data fetched from Database then you can use a Utils class.

**Warning:** Opinion based answer!